# Bluetooth on Lenovo Ideapad S20-30

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, lenovo

Today I installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo S20-30 and most things work but I can't use bluetooth. In the system preferences I can change the bluetooth switch to "on" but when I come back to the pane it is "off" again. Furthermore the bluetooth symbol is missing in the menubar, also the box in the pref pane is checked.

Since I'm completely new to the Linux world I don't know what more information you need for a diagnosis but here are some that maybe help:

```
$ dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[   14.677429] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[   14.677466] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   14.677477] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   14.677481] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   14.677497] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   14.723428] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   14.723443] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   14.723451] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   15.038890] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   15.038895] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   15.038905] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

and

```
$ sudo rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

and

```
$ sudo lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth             446409  10 bnep,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
```

and

```
$ uname -a; lsusb
Linux tobis-lenovo 3.16.0-31-generic #43~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 20:13:38 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 105b:e065  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:054a Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

output form Jeremy31's script:

```
$ dmesg | tail -15
[   18.881813] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2698 mBm), (0 s)
[   18.881816] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[   22.074707] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   22.100053] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   45.348105] audit_printk_skb: 135 callbacks suppressed
[   45.348111] audit: type=1400 audit(1427026413.699:72): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=2333 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   45.348126] audit: type=1400 audit(1427026413.699:73): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2333 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   45.349128] audit: type=1400 audit(1427026413.699:74): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2333 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  154.979500] systemd-hostnamed[2562]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[ 1063.242591] systemd-hostnamed[8556]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[ 2549.195081] systemd-hostnamed[16264]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[ 2712.987102] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[ 2713.065862] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[ 2713.065868] bluetooth hci0: Falling back to user helper
[ 2713.141987] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patch brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd not found
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the results from `uname -a; lsusb`

Comment: @Jeremy31: Thanks, I added the output …

Comment: Yeah – that worked. I added the output to my question. BTW. can I remove all the files and folders your script added to my home folder?

Comment: You can delete the bluetooth-3.16 folder but leave the bluetooth-3.16-2 as it will be needed if your kernel updates.  I will post more instructions on what to do if the kernel updates and bluetooth quits again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this one isn't properly supported in the kernel yet but a fairly easy fix

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/0rmgeve2ibrh1u1/bluetooth-3.16-2.tar.gz
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/f503f6r686riiow/fw-105b_e065.hcd
tar -zxf bluetooth-3.16-2.tar.gz
cd bluetooth-3.16-2
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo modprobe -r btusb && sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Then I need to see what it expects to see the firmware file named, so add the result of `dmesg | tail -15` so I can edit this answer

Now that we know what the firmware needs to be named `cd ~` and `sudo cp fw-105b_e065.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd` and then

```
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
echo btusb | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

And the `dmesg | tail` results should change and bluetooth should work properly

After a kernel update, bluetooth will likely stop functioning, then you need to

```
cd bluetooth-3.16-2
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD clean
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo modprobe -r btusb && sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo modprobe btusb
```

And you should be going until the next update

Comment: Hi, thanks for your guide. I tried to follow it but fails at the second last step (`sudo moprobe -r btsub && …`) with the message that `btsub.ko` can't be copied because it doesn't exist. Actually in `bluethooth-3.16/` there is only on file named `btusb` with suffix `.c` …

Comment: Was there any error after the `make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules` command

Comment: Yes. I overread them in the bunch of lines but I added the output to my question … hope you can read and interpret I  'cause I can't ;-)

Comment: I edited answer to fix that issue with a new download, so run the commands again, start with `cd ~` so you are in your home directory to start

Comment: Great. Bluetooth is working now!

Comment: Hi, is it possible that I missed some thing, because the bluetooth icon disappeard after I restarted …

Comment: Look a my answer at "Now that we know what the firmware needs to be named" and proceed from there.  Likely you need to `sudo modprobe btusb` but the rest of my answer should fix it