# Bluetooth can't be enabled in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, bluetooth

I have this problem since I do a fresh install Ubuntu 14.10 (previously I don't have this problem in 14.04). I tried to follow any instruction available in internet but it doesn't change anything so I have no idea what to do now. [Sreenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B16SKicrViKxUXA1TnVRNFltRnM/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the output of `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`:

```
[   22.521992] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[   22.522014] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   22.522022] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   22.522024] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   22.522036] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   22.573800] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   22.573804] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   22.573812] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 174f:114f Syntek 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 105b:e065  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `lsmod | grep bluetooth`:

```
bluetooth             446190  7 bnep
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
```

Output of `rfkill list all`

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not supported by the Utopic kernel yet, but it can be made to work

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/uocd0xqaprm4yvi/bluetooth.utopic.tar.gz
tar -zxf bluetooth.utopic.tar.gz
cd bluetooth
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/f503f6r686riiow/fw-105b_e065.hcd
sudo cp fw-105b_e065.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd
echo btusb | sudo tee -a /etc/modules && sudo modprobe btusb
```

Then check `dmesg | grep -i firmware` to see if there are any firmware errors and post errors

After a kernel update you will need to recompile the module

```
cd bluetooth
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD clean
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

and bluetooth should work in a new 3.16 series kernel

Comment: I tried that but bluetooth still disabled and this is the output of `dmesg | grep -i firmware`:

`[    0.126121] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored`

Comment: See if it works after a reboot

Comment: Okay, but first I'm gonna try to reinstall the system with download update checked tonight and see if it work and I'll try your advise again, I'll update this comment again as soon as possible

Comment: You could always try http://askubuntu.com/questions/599711/bluetooth-on-lenovo-ideapad-s20-30  as the bluetooth device has the same ID

Comment: Hi @Jeremy31 thanks a lot man, after reinstalling the Ubuntu 14.10 and retry your advise, bluetooth now work.

Comment: I have to do the same as @Jeremy31. Because I tried to change the kernel version following other answer and something did not work right.

Comment: @Orlando Leite  I updated answer to include info on what to do after a kernel change, as long as it is a 3.16 kernel through the Update Manager