# Bluetooth USB dongle 5.0 0a12:0001 doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, bluetooth, patch, diff

**WIRELESS USB DONGLE - BLUETOOTH USB DONGLE - MINI 5.0 - VERSION 5.48 - 0a12:0001**

So lately I bought a Bluetooth USB dongle - model no: MLT-5.0-MiNi

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

**1.** After I connected the adapter into USB port, I checked the port typing in terminal `lsusb` and I got the following:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

**2.** `hciconfig -a` gave the following:

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:11  ACL MTU: 679:9  SCO MTU: 48:16
        DOWN
        RX bytes:574 acl:0 sco:0 events:30 errors:0
        TX bytes:368 acl:0 sco:0 commands:30 errors:0
        Features: 0xff 0xff 0x87 0xfa 0xdb 0xbf 0x7b 0x83
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
        Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

**3.** `hcitool dev`:

```
Devices:
```

So it seemed that my PC didn't have the driver installed.

**4.** `bluetoothctl --version`:

```
bluetoothctl: 5.53
```

**5.** `rfkill`:

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
0  bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
```

**6.** And finally `btmon`:

```
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.53
Failed to bind channel: Operation not permitted
```

---

I found [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/Ain0z2VILY0) to solve the problem.

**1.** First of all, I had to install the app "Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer" to update until the lastest kernel version, so I typed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mainline
```

**2.** Then, before updating to the last kernel version, I had to check what the running kernel version is:

`User@PC:~$ uname -r`

```
5.4.0-48-generic
```

`User@PC:~$ uname -sr`

```
Linux 5.4.0-48-generic
```

**3.** Later I went to the website of [KERNEL](https://www.kernel.org/) and checked what the last Kernel version that's stable is, for example: 5.8.13

After all, I opened the app Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer and clicked the last kernel version that is stable, for example: 5.8.13. Finally clicked the button **Install**.

**4.** After the installation and reboot, I checked again:

`User@PC:~$ uname -r`

```
5.8.13-050813-generic
```

`User@PC:~$ uname -sr`

```
Linux 5.8.13-050813-generic
```

I saw that it was successful, and the bluetooth USB DONGLE 5.0 is working.

**BUT THERE IS ONE PROBLEM TO CONNECT AFTER  PAIRING**: After pairing Ubuntu with my speaker 5.0, it cannot connect, then after pairing Ubuntu with my smartphone LG, I couldn't send any pictures to smartphone from Ubuntu nor vice versa.

**1.** I typed `systemctl status bluetooth` and entered.

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-10-03 19:02:12 -05; 10min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 2173 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4649)
     Memory: 2.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─2173 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

oct 03 19:02:11 PC systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
oct 03 19:02:12 PC bluetoothd[2173]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
oct 03 19:02:12 PC systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
oct 03 19:02:12 PC bluetoothd[2173]: Starting SDP server
oct 03 19:02:12 PC bluetoothd[2173]: Bluetooth management interface 1.17 initialized
oct 03 19:02:13 PC bluetoothd[2173]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
oct 03 19:02:14 PC bluetoothd[2173]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
oct 03 19:02:14 PC bluetoothd[2173]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.75 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
oct 03 19:02:14 PC bluetoothd[2173]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
```

I see that there is a problem:

```
bluetoothd[2173]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
```

**2.** `rfkill list`:

```
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**3.** `hciconfig -a`:

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:11  ACL MTU: 679:9  SCO MTU: 48:16
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:1174 acl:0 sco:0 events:65 errors:0
    TX bytes:1046 acl:0 sco:0 commands:65 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0x87 0xfa 0xdb 0xbf 0x7b 0x83
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'Daniel-MS-7529'
    Class: 0x1c0104
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Desktop workstation
    HCI Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Revision: 0x810
    LMP Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Subversion: 0x2312
    Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
```

I see that everything is OK.

**4.** `btmon`:

```
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.53
Failed to bind channel: Operation not permitted
```

**5.** `sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`:

```
[  132.146271] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  132.146302] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  132.146308] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  132.146310] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  132.146314] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  132.515401] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds...
[  133.859424] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  133.859426] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  133.859431] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  135.263551] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  135.263561] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  135.263570] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1017.955624] Bluetooth: hci0: inquiry failed: status 0x0c
[ 1023.331631] Bluetooth: hci0: inquiry failed: status 0x0c
[ 3305.392256] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds...
```

There is one more problem:

```
Bluetooth: hci0: inquiry failed: status 0x0c
```

**6.** Another time, I typed on the terminal `hcidump -X` and entered and then I went to the setting of Bluetooth to try to pair and connect the speaker and I got the following results on the terminal:

```
HCI sniffer - Bluetooth packet analyzer ver 5.53
device: hci0 snap_len: 1500 filter: 0xffffffffffffffff
```

[several lines related to HCI Event]

```
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Inquiry (0x01|0x0001) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Extended Inquiry Result (0x2f) plen 255
    bdaddr 88:D0:39:7C:24:61 mode 1 clkoffset 0x2744 class 0x240404 rssi -25
    Complete local name: 'Soundcore Flare+'
    Unknown type 0xff with 9 bytes data
> HCI Event: Extended Inquiry Result (0x2f) plen 255
    bdaddr 24:FC:E5:6E:53:5B mode 1 clkoffset 0x18bd class 0x08043c rssi -71
> HCI Event: Extended Inquiry Result (0x2f) plen 255
    bdaddr 24:FC:E5:6E:53:5B mode 1 clkoffset 0x18bd class 0x08043c rssi -98
> HCI Event: Inquiry Complete (0x01) plen 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Random Address (0x08|0x0005) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Inquiry (0x01|0x0001) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Disconn Complete (0x05) plen 4
    status 0x00 handle 128 reason 0x16
    Reason: Connection Terminated by Local Host
> HCI Event: Extended Inquiry Result (0x2f) plen 255
    bdaddr 88:D0:39:7C:24:61 mode 1 clkoffset 0x2745 class 0x240404 rssi -25
    Complete local name: 'Soundcore Flare+'
    Unknown type 0xff with 9 bytes data
> HCI Event: Inquiry Complete (0x01) plen 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Random Address (0x08|0x0005) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Inquiry (0x01|0x0001) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Extended Inquiry Result (0x2f) plen 255
    bdaddr 88:D0:39:7C:24:61 mode 1 clkoffset 0x2745 class 0x240404 rssi -27
    Complete local name: 'Soundcore Flare+'
    Unknown type 0xff with 9 bytes data
> HCI Event: Extended Inquiry Result (0x2f) plen 255
    bdaddr 88:D0:39:7C:24:61 mode 1 clkoffset 0x2745 class 0x240404 rssi -27
    Complete local name: 'Soundcore Flare+'
    Unknown type 0xff with 9 bytes data
> HCI Event: Extended Inquiry Result (0x2f) plen 255
    bdaddr 88:D0:39:7C:24:61 mode 1 clkoffset 0x2745 class 0x240404 rssi -24
    Complete local name: 'Soundcore Flare+'
    Unknown type 0xff with 9 bytes data
> HCI Event: Extended Inquiry Result (0x2f) plen 255
    bdaddr 88:D0:39:7C:24:61 mode 1 clkoffset 0x2745 class 0x240404 rssi -24
    Complete local name: 'Soundcore Flare+'
    Unknown type 0xff with 9 bytes data
> HCI Event: Extended Inquiry Result (0x2f) plen 255
    bdaddr 88:D0:39:7C:24:61 mode 1 clkoffset 0x2745 class 0x240404 rssi -23
    Complete local name: 'Soundcore Flare+'
    Unknown type 0xff with 9 bytes data
> HCI Event: Extended Inquiry Result (0x2f) plen 255
    bdaddr 88:D0:39:7C:24:61 mode 1 clkoffset 0x2745 class 0x240404 rssi -24
    Complete local name: 'Soundcore Flare+'
    Unknown type 0xff with 9 bytes data
> HCI Event: Extended Inquiry Result (0x2f) plen 255
    bdaddr 88:D0:39:7C:24:61 mode 1 clkoffset 0x2745 class 0x240404 rssi -23
    Complete local name: 'Soundcore Flare+'
    Unknown type 0xff with 9 bytes data
> HCI Event: Extended Inquiry Result (0x2f) plen 255
    bdaddr 88:D0:39:7C:24:61 mode 1 clkoffset 0x2745 class 0x240404 rssi -22
    Complete local name: 'Soundcore Flare+'
    Unknown type 0xff with 9 bytes data
```

Soundcore Flare+ is the speaker's model. I see there is one another problem:

```
Unknown type 0xff with 9 bytes data
```

---

The Bluetooth USB 5.0 works fine on Windows 10 but on Ubuntu 20.04, it doesn't work. So Ubuntu needs drivers for Bluetooth 5.0.

On 5.8.14 Kernel, Ubuntu really displays devices to pair and connect, but the pairing and connecting don't work.

So, could anyone help me to solve this problem of pairing and connecting with devices from Ubuntu?

I found the problem solved for Linux in [this website](https://fosspost.org/linux-bluetooth-problem/) but I don't know how to compile and patch on Ubuntu 20.04, it can work only for Kernel's version 5.8.

Comment: It's possible that you've gone deep down an incorrect path.  What is the exact make/model of the wireless adapter?  The problem is likely hardware specific.  Have you consulted with the manufacturer's documentation?

Comment: In terminal try `sudo hciconfig hci0 up`

Comment: @Nmath MODEL No: MLT-5.0-MiNi but no matter what model is, the matter is the chip: 0a12:0001

Comment: @Jeremy31 result: Can't init device hci0: Operation not supported (95)

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `rfkill list`

Comment: @Nmath Some of them are supported but there are a lot of devices using that same USB ID and it makes it a pain for the kernel devs.  Back in 2014 there was actually a module parameter to ignore that device as it was that much of a problem

Comment: @Nmath I bought the bluetooth USB without any driver. I posted my problem for engineers to help me to solve the problem. Engineers can compile the source code to solve the problem.

Comment: You might want to install UKUU from github and see if installing the 5.8.10 kernel fixes the issue as that patch is part of that kernel

Comment: @Jeremy31 rfkill included.

Comment: I found the solved problem: https://fosspost.org/linux-bluetooth-problem/
But I don't know what steps are to apply the patch to kernel on Ubuntu.

Comment: A quick Google search showed many different problems with this hardware, including fakes on the market that present as 0a12:0001, but lack the features or are simply broken. The patch *might* solve your problem if you learn how to compile it...but also might not. [Previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208296), [One of many Launchpad bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1879124), [Upstream bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60824) discussing some of the problems. Honestly, it might be cheaper and faster to buy a not-quite-so-cheap BT dongle.

Comment: The Bluetooth USB 5.0 works fine on Windows 10 but on Ubuntu 20.04, it doesn't work. So Ubuntu needs drivers for Bluetooth 5.0. On 5.8.14 Kernel, Ubuntu really display devices to pair and connect, but the pairing and connecting don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with 0a12/0001 under Ubuntu 20.04.4. My second computer works with debian 11 bullseye, where the adapter works fine. There I found an installed package which isn't installed in Ubuntu 20.04 by default. So in 20.04 try installing the **bluetooth** package. Works for Vendor 0a12/0001.
Open a terminal and type `sudo apt install bluetooth`