# Problem using Bluetooth usb dongle

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, blueman

I've bought a Bluetooth USB which works ok in Windows (dual boot), but not in my Ubuntu.

```
$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-12-25 01:46:33 -03; 21h ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 719 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38375)
     Memory: 1.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─719 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

dez 25 01:46:33 g-Z390-M systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
dez 25 01:46:33 g-Z390-M bluetoothd[719]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
dez 25 01:46:33 g-Z390-M systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
dez 25 01:46:33 g-Z390-M bluetoothd[719]: Starting SDP server
dez 25 01:46:33 g-Z390-M bluetoothd[719]: Bluetooth management interface 1.19 initialized
```

but when using blueman, I get the following

```
$ blueman-manager 
blueman-manager version 2.1.2 starting
Failed to enable bluetooth
blueman-manager 22.59.46 ERROR    Manager:118 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.
blueman-manager 22.59.46 ERROR    Manager:122 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with kernel 5.11.0-43-generic. The following holds

```
$ lsmod | grep -i blu
bluetooth             638976  12 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetoot

$ sudo rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

Comment: When dual-booting with Windows, disabling its Fast Startup feature (followed by a shutdown, not reboot) is a must. Do that and try again. Update your question accodingly by [edit]ing it.

Comment: What is the make/model of the Bluetooth adapter?  Alternatively if you know the chipset, provide that. Many wireless issues are hardware specific.

Comment: Is your dongle HCI compliant?  You can check by terminal command; lsusb.  IF your dongle is recognised, it will be listed, and the description should include '(HCI)' . Pls provide this info.  If not, your dongle may be incompatible.

Comment: Yeah, it is "Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)" updated the question with this info. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @Nmath, actualy no. This dongle is one of thoses cheap ones. The only info is that it is written "csr 4.0"

Comment: Actually, yes! You even posted the chipset info in the comment you added 2 minutes earlier.  The entity that produced your dongle did not fab the Bluetooth chip inside the thing.  As I also pointed out in my comment, most wireless issues are hardware specific. There is an existing question about this chipset that has an accepted solution: https://askubuntu.com/q/1208296 There are a few others. Just search "0a12:0001" Good Luck!