# I can't activate my bluetooth Cambridge Silicon Radio Dongle (2022)

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to activate my Bluetooth Dongle Cambridge Silicon Radio. I did a research and can't find an updated solution, since older solutions aren't working anymore: https://gist.github.com/nevack/6b36b82d715dc025163d9e9124840a07

Here all the info I can get:

Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 21.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.22.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.86.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-39-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 6 × AMD Ryzen 5 3500X 6-Core Processor
Memory: 15.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon RX 560 Series

lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)

hcidumb:
HCI sniffer - Bluetooth packet analyzer ver 5.60
device: hci0 snap_len: 1500 filter: 0xffffffffffffffff

Comment: There's a kernel patch mentioned on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1222944/167115). Also, a [bug mentioned here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60824) claims that it's working on kernel 5.17 out of the box (it "never worked before" on previous kernels). The only kernel 5.17 for Ubuntu that I could find is [available for 22.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-image-5.17&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) which will be officially released in a few days. You might need the headers as well. Although, there is no guarantee 5.17 will work.

Comment: Type `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`to see what is going at at boot and then type `mokutil --sb-state` to confirm that secure boot it off.