# Doesn't working Bluetooth on Ubuntu 20.04/22.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, 22.04

I have the issue with USB Bluetooth adapter. For info:

```
nikita@nikita-desktop:~$ rfkill list
1: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

nikita@nikita-desktop:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 045e:07f8 Microsoft Corp. Wired Keyboard 600 (model 1576)
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04e8:6864 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9070 (network tethering, USB debugging enabled)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1b3f:2247 Generalplus Technology Inc. GENERAL WEBCAM
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:00cb Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse v2.0
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

nikita@nikita-desktop:~$ lsmod | grep btusb
btusb 61440 0
btrtl 24576 1 btusb
btbcm 20480 1 btusb
btintel 32768 1 btusb
bluetooth 651264 12 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb

nikita@nikita-desktop:~$ bluetoothctl list

nikita@nikita-desktop:~$ systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enable>
Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-04-17 16:57:17 EEST; 37min ago
Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
Main PID: 3712 (bluetoothd)
Status: "Running"
Tasks: 1 (limit: 9012)
Memory: 508.0K
CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
└─3712 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

апр 17 16:57:17 nikita-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
апр 17 16:57:17 nikita-desktop bluetoothd[3712]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
апр 17 16:57:17 nikita-desktop systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
апр 17 16:57:17 nikita-desktop bluetoothd[3712]: Starting SDP server
апр 17 16:57:17 nikita-desktop bluetoothd[3712]: Bluetooth management interface 1.20 initi>
lines 1-16/16 (END)
```

My version kernel: 5.17.5.
On Windows 11 Bluetooth working very good

UPD:

```
nikita@nikita-desktop:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[sudo] пароль для nikita: 
[    2.940237] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.940259] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    2.940260] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.940263] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.940264] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.940267] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.024145] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[    3.847334] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.847337] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.847339] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    8.231573] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Couldn't suspend the device for our Barrot 8041a02 receive-issue workaround
[   10.246870] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
```

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: hello. I added in description

Comment: It looks like this device isn't supported.

Comment: What's to do? I can't to leave Windows, if bluetooth doesn't working,

Comment: Someone says that a kernel patch is needed, someone says that the kernel needs to be updated, the third is something else.

Comment: The easiest way is to buy another dongle. This one is problematic, because a lot of devices share the same ID. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208296/bluetooth-adapter-configuration-issue-id-0a120001

Comment: I can't to buy another key

Comment: I read it, but it didn't help me

Comment: If you can't afford this my sympathies: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001781383090.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.109d50abJ9hiXy&algo_pvid=c80b7e3d-0885-4011-8469-7ddc99848d16&algo_exp_id=c80b7e3d-0885-4011-8469-7ddc99848d16-0&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000017546139860%22%7D&pdp_npi=1%40dis%7CEUR%7C%7C2.57%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%402100bdd016511855173377075e99c3%7C12000017546139860%7Csea

Comment: I cant to buy new dongle.