# Ubuntu 15.04 - Bluetooth - No adapters found - Dell Precision M4800

Tags: bluetooth, 15.04

Post Ubuntu 15.04 upgrade, I found that the bluetooth was disabled on my machine. I went ahead and enabled the same and since then my Blueman Bluetooth Manager does not help me set up my devices.

Details of my configuration:

`sudo service bluetooth status`:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2015-04-26 18:53:35 IST; 4s ago
 Main PID: 5106 (bluetoothd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─5106 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd -n

Apr 26 18:53:35 UBUGROUND bluetoothd[5106]: Failed to init time plugin
Apr 26 18:53:35 UBUGROUND bluetoothd[5106]: Failed to init alert plugin
Apr 26 18:53:35 UBUGROUND bluetoothd[5106]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
Apr 26 18:53:35 UBUGROUND bluetoothd[5106]: bluetoothd[5106]: Failed to init time plugin
Apr 26 18:53:35 UBUGROUND bluetoothd[5106]: bluetoothd[5106]: Failed to init alert plugin
Apr 26 18:53:35 UBUGROUND bluetoothd[5106]: bluetoothd[5106]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
Apr 26 18:53:35 UBUGROUND bluetoothd[5106]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Apr 26 18:53:35 UBUGROUND bluetoothd[5106]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
Apr 26 18:53:35 UBUGROUND bluetoothd[5106]: bluetoothd[5106]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Apr 26 18:53:35 UBUGROUND bluetoothd[5106]: bluetoothd[5106]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
```

`dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`:

```
[ 7583.148359] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[ 7583.148372] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 7583.148376] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 7583.148377] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 7583.148381] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 7583.176193] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 7583.176195] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 7583.176198] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

`sudo lshw -class network`:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: f0:1f:af:62:48:8f
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:28 memory:f7400000-f741ffff memory:f7439000-f7439fff ioport:f040(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 03
       serial: 40:f0:2f:7e:8a:71
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=10.179.108.111 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:18 memory:f5400000-f5407fff memory:f5200000-f53fffff
```

`sudo rfkill list all`

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`sudo lsusb; uname -a; lsmod | grep bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware`:

```
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0a5c:5801 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor with fingerprint swipe sensor
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 413c:8143 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0c45:649d Microdia 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 413c:5534 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04fc:0c25 Sunplus Technology Co., Ltd SATALink SPIF225A
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:2134 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2513 Dell Computer Corp. internal USB Hub of E-Port Replicator
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Linux UBUGROUND 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 16 23:32:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
bluetooth             491520  10 bnep,rfcomm
[    0.194851] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
```

Further to Jerry's inputs, the issue got resolved with the following dmesg | tail dump for verification

```
[ 9134.675919] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 9134.675922] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 9134.675928] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9134.675933] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9134.675937] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9134.675941] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9134.675944] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[14583.328619] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[14583.373507] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patching hci_ver=06 hci_rev=1000 lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=220e
[14584.111182] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware hci_ver=06 hci_rev=15a9 lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=220e
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be easy

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/3jqigkapf383tod/bluetooth-15.04.tar.gz
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgcu075lvvzq690/BCM20702A0-413c-8143.hcd
sudo cp BCM20702A0-413c-8143.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/
tar -zxf bluetooth-15.04.tar.gz
cd bluetooth
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Then check to see if firmware loaded `dmesg | tail` please post this in a comment or edit your question to include

```
echo btusb | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

When your kernel updates, the bluetooth will fail until you

```
cd bluetooth
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD clean
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. Updated my question with the dump for `dmesg | tail`

Comment: I expected some kind of firmware loading confirmation in `dmesg | tail `  I will edit my answer to include info on how to get it going again when you get a new kernel through updates

Comment: On a different note, I noticed that Blueman Bluetooth Manager was taxing my laptop's processor/something. Had removed it and rebooted my machine. Everything seems normal now.

Comment: I removed blueman from my computers as it made it a pain to use bluetooth audio.  At every boot blueman removes module-bluetooth-discover which is needed

Comment: I have upgraded my ubuntu to 15.04 too. I did the same, again, except my bluetooth is `fw-105b_e065.hcd`.  But it didn't work. I would like to ignore bluetooth, but it interferes somehow on wifi connection range.

Comment: @Orlando Leite `sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/81-bluetooth-hci.rules` and add `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="105b", ATTRS{idProduct}=="e065", ATTR{authorized}="0"`  Save and reboot.  It shouldn't even be anything in `rfkill list all` and it should only be seen in `lsusb`

Comment: @Jeremy31 It appears as `Bus 003 Device 004: ID 105b:e065 ` but, without a name. Removing and replacing btusb I got `Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20; HCI, L2CAP,  SCO socket layer initialized` and the last line: `usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb` on `dmesg`. The most relevant  thing I found in dmesg was `[Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored`. BTW, I followed your answers before. nice.

Comment: This worked for me but as soon as I rebooted then Bluetooth was not working again unless I ran the specified commands each time. Is there a way to make it stick?

Comment: @Orlando Leite I just updated my code for your device and you can find the hcd file from this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/599711/bluetooth-on-lenovo-ideapad-s20-30)  basically `wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/f503f6r686riiow/fw-105b_e065.hcd` and then `sudo cp fw-105b_e065.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd`

Comment: @cpgascho `echo btusb | sudo tee -a /etc/modules` should work to load the module each boot unless you are booting the "Try Ubuntu without installing"

Comment: @OrlandoLeite `sudo update-usbids` should add a better description to `lsusb`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Someone removed the line `{ USB_DEVICE(0x105b, 0xe065), .driver_info = BTUSB_BCM_PATCHRAM },` from `btusb.c`. I put and recompile so now this shows `hci0 urb ffff880191b19c00 failed to resubmit (2); hci0: HCI_OP_RESET failed (-19)` on `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`

Comment: @OrlandoLeite What kernel?

Comment: @Jeremy31 `3.19.0-16-generic`. Should I open another question for this version of bluetooth `0x105b:0xe065`?

Comment: @OrlandoLeite just double check the source code for btusb.c  I added your device to line 113, if you don't see it on 113 start a new question

Comment: Yes, it is there. No, it didn't work. Stuck on comment #7.

Comment: Have you shut down and rebooted using the hcd file from my comment?

Comment: In windows it has stopped working too. I reset the bios (optimized defaults) and, voila, it comes back to work on both. But, my recommendation to myself is, buy another wifi. So pour quality signal, loses packages, sometimes it screws the internet for all people on the same spot.