# Bluetooth adapter not found in lenevo G50-80 with ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, 15.04, bluetooth

My dmesg | grep Blue output is as below

```
[    6.027325] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    6.027338] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.027341] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.027343] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.027346] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.222201] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 3707100100012d0d18
[    6.222204] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 18
[   19.996510] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   19.996513] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   19.996518] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   20.001465] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   20.001473] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   20.001478] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

and lsusb output is

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp.

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:055d Acer, Inc 

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

sudo service bluetooth status

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Aug 13 00:37:17 r bluetoothd[742]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.43 path=/MediaEndpoint/BlueZ4/HFPHS
Aug 13 00:37:17 r systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Aug 13 00:37:17 r systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.
Aug 13 00:37:17 r bluetoothd[742]: bluetoothd[742]: Terminating
Aug 13 00:37:17 r bluetoothd[742]: bluetoothd[742]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.43 path=/MediaEndpoint/BlueZ4/A2DPSink
Aug 13 00:37:17 r bluetoothd[742]: bluetoothd[742]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.43 path=/MediaEndpoint/BlueZ4/A2DPSource
Aug 13 00:37:17 r bluetoothd[742]: bluetoothd[742]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.43 path=/MediaEndpoint/BlueZ4/HFPAG
Aug 13 00:37:17 r bluetoothd[742]: bluetoothd[742]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.43 path=/MediaEndpoint/BlueZ4/HFPHS
Aug 13 00:37:17 r bluetoothd[742]: bluetoothd[742]: Stopping SDP server
Aug 13 00:37:17 r bluetoothd[742]: bluetoothd[742]: Exit
```

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 with kubuntu plasma desktop

My bluetooth is in disable mode when i click on it then "no adapter found" message is coming I had followed step of below link

```
[http://askubuntu.com/questions/614319/ubuntu-15-04-bluetooth-no-adapters-found-dell-precision-m4800][1]
```

but its not work for me

could you please provide solution for me.

Comment: Please {edit] your question and add output of `rfkill list` command.