# Ubuntu 15.10 - Bluetooth - No adapters found

Tags: 15.04, 15.10, bluetooth

Post Ubuntu 15.10 upgrade from 15.04, there was no more Bluetooth adapter found. I tried to install Bluetooth Manager but it didn't help me set up my devices.

I found out the following post ([Ubuntu 15.04 - Bluetooth - No adapters found - Dell Precision M4800](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614319/ubuntu-15-04-bluetooth-no-adapters-found-dell-precision-m4800)) and tried to follow it but didn't get anywhere

Details of my configuration:

sudo service bluetooth status

```
    ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-04-18 06:41:29 EEST; 13h ago
         Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
     Main PID: 2530 (bluetoothd)
       Status: "Running"
       CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
               └─2530 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

    Apr 18 18:38:43 Keinux bluetoothd[2530]: Current Time Service could not be registered
    Apr 18 18:38:43 Keinux bluetoothd[2530]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
    Apr 18 18:38:43 Keinux bluetoothd[2530]: Not enough free handles to register service
    Apr 18 18:38:43 Keinux bluetoothd[2530]: Not enough free handles to register service
    Apr 18 18:38:43 Keinux bluetoothd[2530]: Sap driver initialization failed.
    Apr 18 18:38:43 Keinux bluetoothd[2530]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
    Apr 18 18:38:43 Keinux bluetoothd[2530]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.41 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
    Apr 18 18:38:43 Keinux bluetoothd[2530]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.41 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
    Apr 18 18:44:20 Keinux bluetoothd[2530]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.41 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
    Apr 18 18:44:20 Keinux bluetoothd[2530]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.41 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

dmesg | grep -i bluetooth:

```
    [   91.574557] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
    [   91.574585] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
    [   91.574590] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
    [   91.574593] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
    [   91.574600] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
    [   91.800069] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
    [   91.800076] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
    [   91.800086] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
    [   91.823779] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
    [   91.823788] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
    [   91.823797] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

sudo lshw -class network

```
      *-network               
           description: Ethernet interface
           product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           physical id: 0.2
           bus info: pci@0000:03:00.2
           logical name: eth0
           version: 0a
           serial: 00:90:f5:cc:99:56
           size: 10Mbit/s
           capacity: 1Gbit/s
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.3 06/18/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
           resources: irq:27 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:ec104000-ec104fff memory:ec100000-ec103fff
      *-network
           description: Wireless interface
           product: Centrino Wireless-N 130
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
           logical name: wlan0
           version: 34
           serial: dc:a9:71:84:ee:f5
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.2.0-35-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.8.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
           resources: irq:31 memory:f6900000-f6901fff
```

sudo rfkill list all

```
    0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

sudo lsusb; uname -a; lsmod | grep bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware

```
    Bus 004 Device 004: ID 5986:0361 Acer, Inc 
    Bus 004 Device 003: ID 147e:1002 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
    Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Linux Keinux 4.2.0-35-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 15 19:53:28 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
    bluetooth             466944  12 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
    [    4.754272] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
    [    6.570158] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
```

Comment: Did bluetooth work in 15.04?

Comment: Yep, it was working fine on 15.04.

Comment: Sorry, but I just got some updates and it works now as well as before.