# Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 14.04 with Wily kernel (4.2)

Tags: 14.04, kernel, bluetooth

I have a Dell Precision M4800 using Ubuntu 14.04.4 with Wily kernel (4.2.0-35). Bluetooth is not working for me. Tried the steps in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614319/ubuntu-15-04-bluetooth-no-adapters-found-dell-precision-m4800/767006#767006) question, as my setup seems to be exactly the same as the one described (except for the Ubuntu version), but I get a:

```
/bluetooth/hci_h4.c:128:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘hci_recv_stream_fragment’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

Which I think is normal.... Where can I find the bluetooth source for my SO version?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I can answer myself...

I've got the correct kernel source this way:

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Got the bluetooth folder in /drivers/bluetooth/, and added the following line in btusb.c under the /*Broadcom BCM20702A0 */ comment as described [here](http://blog.tkassembled.com/301/patching-btusb-to-enable-compatibility-with-the-bcm20702a0-chip/):

```
{ USB_DEVICE(0x413c, 0x8143) },
```

Then simply followed the rest of the steps (from the sixth on) described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614319/ubuntu-15-04-bluetooth-no-adapters-found-dell-precision-m4800/767006#767006) by Jeremy31.

And it worked like a charm ;)

Comment: Glad you found an answer of mine that was helpful