# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS - Bluetooth - No adapters found - Dell Precision M4800

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, dell

I have been trying to connect my headphones or my phone to the computer but it always get stuck on Searching for devices... I have tried to apply [this thread solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614319/ubuntu-15-04-bluetooth-no-adapters-found-dell-precision-m4800) but the second file is unavailable and looks like there is no other backup file on the internet. My outputs are:

`sudo service bluetooth status:`

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-05-11 19:25:03 CST; 19min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 965 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18961)
     Memory: 1.9M
        CPU: 126ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─965 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

may 11 19:25:03 frankusky-Precision-M4800 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
may 11 19:25:03 frankusky-Precision-M4800 bluetoothd[965]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
may 11 19:25:03 frankusky-Precision-M4800 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
may 11 19:25:03 frankusky-Precision-M4800 bluetoothd[965]: Starting SDP server
may 11 19:25:03 frankusky-Precision-M4800 bluetoothd[965]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
```

`sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth:`

```
[    4.078951] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.078952] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.078955] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.078957] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.078960] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.207441] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[    4.208445] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
[    4.224452] Bluetooth: hci0: frankusky-Precision-M4800
[    4.224460] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[    4.232456] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[    4.232492] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM20702A1-413c-8143.hcd'
[    4.232512] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM-413c-8143.hcd'
[    6.159869] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.159874] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.159879] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   32.520607] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   32.520617] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   32.520624] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   43.035687] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x 402 failed: -22
```

`sudo lsusb; uname -a; lsmod | grep bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware:`

```
us 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:8143 Dell Computer Corp. Broadcom BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:649d Microdia Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Linux frankusky-Precision-M4800 5.19.0-41-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Apr 18 17:40:00 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
bluetooth             827392  42 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Try `cd /lib/firmware/brcm && sudo wget https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/raw/master/brcm/BCM20702A1-413c-8143.hcd` then reboot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working)

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy31, for the first answer, it now finds the device but still can´t connect, it disconnects immediately. For the second answer, I cant convert the file, it returns an empty file

Comment: Also I dont know if this helps, but I have windows in other partition and the bluetooth works fine there, I dont know if I can gather the firmware somewhere there

Comment: @Jeremy31 now its workiiiiiing!!! On the second answer they shared a github repo that has the converted file, with the file, I followed all the steps that the original answer says. However, this didnt work, but after searching on internet, they mention change `ControllerMode` to `bredr` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and reboot, and it worked! If you want, write this as answer to give you the points. TYSM