# Bluetooth on Lenovo G780

Tags: bluetooth, 15.04

It's just not working. In bluetooth settings it says that bluetooth is disabled and switching it does nothing.

```
~$ rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

~$ lsusb    
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 5986:0295 Acer, Inc 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 105b:e065  
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

~$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[  109.229291] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[  109.229318] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  109.229324] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  109.229329] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  109.229338] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  109.293703] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  109.293712] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  109.293722] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Yes, I installed firmware for 105b:e065 and bluetooth is initializing now but still not working. Also:

```
~$ hcitool dev
Devices:
```

It's blank and I can do nothing with hci.

Comment: What kernel? `uname -a`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04; 3.19.0-18-generic

Comment: I can get it working but I would like you to file a bug report, some info [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug) on getting started.  After my fix has been proven to work, then it can be submitted upstream.  If you want, you could install Ubuntu 14.04.2 and use the fix from [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/599711/bluetooth-on-lenovo-ideapad-s20-30)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until I can get a dkms done for this, the following will work until a kernel update

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/kj6w4qkantc8sul/btusb-vivid.tar.gz
tar -zxvf btusb-vivid.tar.gz
cd btusb-2.0
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Got a dkms one done

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/texcobck1yjvhzc/btusb-dkms_2.0_all.deb
dpkg -i btusb-dkms_2.0_all.deb
```

Reboot

Comment: It is quite easy to make a dkms of a single module. Look at my dkms.conf at ppa. Just change module name. If you send me a btusb file with all changes, I will post it to ppa next week.

Comment: Why download link is to 2.0, but install command to 1.1? Is it a typo?

Comment: @Pilot6 wrong file name originally.  The only change is to include `{ USB_VENDOR_AND_INTERFACE_INFO(0x105b, 0xff, 0x01, 0x01),
   .driver_info = BTUSB_BCM_PATCHRAM },` in the device id table

Comment: I fixed it. You can push this to a ppa. Or maybe it makes sense to collect all this type of additions and add them to a custom btusb ppa.

Comment: @Pilot6 I see this was already submitted http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=143205702711960&w=2

Comment: That's true, but without `Cc: stable@vger.kernel.org` it won't reach stable Ubuntu kernels. I want to make a ppa with btusb-dkms to make it available for current users.