# Laptop Lenovo G510 bluetooth doesn't work Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: bluetooth

i am totally new in Linux. I'm trying to find out how to get the bluetooth activated. I have searched so far in the web but no solution works. Please tell me what commands I should provide so you understand the problem. Thanks in advance!

these are the results:

```
fotis@fotis-Lenovo-G510:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0611]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

http://paste.ubuntu.com/13514981/

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 105b:e065

fotis@fotis-Lenovo-G510:~$ uname -a
Linux fotis-Lenovo-G510 3.19.0-33-generic #38~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

modinfo btusb | grep -i 105b  does nothing

I tried this [Bluetooth on Lenovo Ideapad S20-30](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599711/bluetooth-on-lenovo-ideapad-s20-30) but sometime it stops (probably needs different file).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I do not see any bluetooth modules in `lsusb`. Try to run `sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop` and try again `lsusb`.

Comment: it prints out the same

Comment: Check bios or reset it to defaults and try `lsusb` again. BT will not work until it is seen there. It maybe seen not as a bluetooth device, but it should appear somehow.

Comment: And are you sure there is BT in this laptop?

Comment: it is supposed to have one

Comment: There is a new line. Is this the bluetooth?

Comment: Yes, it is the bluetooth. See the link above. There are directions to get it work.

Comment: It should work. I made firmware for exactly that chip.

Comment: I am not sure that this bluetooth is supported in the kernel, please edit question to include `uname -a; modinfo btusb | grep -i 105b` Thanks

Comment: I have already tried the solution of duplicate but still the firmware is not installed. Any other ideas? I suppose that this firmware is not supported in this kernel (3.19.0)